# C-E leakage current, breakdown voltage in 2N2222A

Tags: transistors

I was trying to control the remote start circuit for a generator. The circuit operates on a 12V automotive battery, so it's around 13.5V. The circuit draws around 13mA. I grabbed a 2N2222A and wired up a simple circuit with the generator control inputs on the collector and emitter. With the base at ground, the generator fired up as soon as I connected it across C-E. I didn't expect this.

I went back to the bench and hooked up a 9V battery across the C-E and measured 165mA. Then I read the datasheet more carefully. The max C-E breakdown voltage rating is 40V, but that's at 10mA. I try some more experimentation. Add a 1.5K resistor in series with the 9V battery, for a max 6mA. Now the leakage across C-E is .3mA. Try a 510 ohm resistor (18mA) - leakage has jumped to about 6mA.

What in the datasheet should have warned me that this transistor was unsuitable for this application?

EDIT:
Forget all that about the generator - it's just a distraction where I was attempting to explain why I was trying this experiment.

Just look at this very simple circuit:
[image]

With a 1.5K resister, the meter shows about .3mA. With a 500 ohm resistor current jumps to about 6mA.

I tried this with a half dozen transistors from 3 different batches. One batch is claimed to be genuine Fairchild parts. All act pretty much the same.

Comment: We probably need to see something from you in terms of exactly how you wired things up. Also, very *scary things* can happen to the voltage when first starting a car or shutting it off (load dump events.) So you need to disclose if you were all connected up and then used a starter motor or shut things off. Finally, it would help if you had a second 2N2222A to use in order to see if a virgin device behaves the same way. It's too early (jumping the gun) to tell you about datasheets, I think. We need to take careful steps first so that we understand exactly what's been happening and how.

Answer (score 1):

Note the variants in pinouts (image from Wikipedia):

[image]

I would also not be totally gobsmacked to see a "2222" made with Japanese-standard E-C-B pinout from some Asian source. Check an unsullied transistor with diode range on a multimeter.

The diode forward voltage that is slightly lower than the other is the C-B junction. Or plug it into the hFE tester on your multimeter- assuming only E/C are unknown from your diode test and the higher gain identifies the correct orientation. Usually they won't be close (like ~10 vs. ~200).

---

As far as what could kill a correctly connected transistor, should that happen, the culprit could be an inductive load or a violation of the safe operating area (SOA). If no SOA chart is shown on the datasheet, avoid combinations of high Vce with high current  (as can happen when switching an inductive load, even with a flyback diode). A beefier transistor (for example using a 600mA transistor to switch a 150mA inductive load rather than a 200mA transistor) usually prevents any problems. Without a flyback diode, of course the energy in the magnetic field goes into the tiny transistor die and can damage it if/when it avalanches, at more than 40V in this case.

Comment: The device I'm testing is labeled PN2222A. However, I'm using the pinout as shown in the ON Semi datasheet, which is CBE. Testing with meter as you suggest is consistent with this pinout. When used in a 5V circuit (ie, 5V at B to switch 5V across C-E), it works as expected, leading me to believe I have the right pinout.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably connected it backward. Recheck the connections, there are a couple of different pinouts depending upon the specific device.

Commmon arrangements are base-collector-emitter or emitter-base-collector.

In the reverse direction, the base-emitter junction will breakdown at about 6-7V. That would be consistent with your second experiment.